# Intersection of Kummer extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, field-theory, galois-theory

Let $p$ and $q$ be two prime numbers and $\omega$ be the primitive 3rd root of unity. The splitting field of $X^3-p$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is $K_p=\mathbb{Q}(p^{\frac{1}{3}},\omega)$ and we have a similar description for $K_q$.

> How to show that $K_p\cap K_q=\mathbb{Q}(\omega)$? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $[K_p:Q]=[K_q:Q]=6$, and $[Q(\omega):Q]=2$. You know that $Q(\omega)\subset K_p\cap K_q$, thus $[K_p:K_p\cap K_q]=1$ or $3$. If it is $1$, then $q^{1/3}\in K_p$. This implies that $K_p=K_q$. Write $q^{1/3}=a+bp^{1/3}+cq^{2/3}$. Let $s$ be a non trivial element of $Gal(K_p:Q)$ such that $s(p^{1/3})=\omega p^{1/3}$. We have $s(q^{1/3})=a+\omega p^{1/3}+\omega^2p^{2/3}$. Since $s(q^{1/3})\in\{q^{1/3},\omega q^{1/3},\omega^2q^{2/3}\}$, we deduce that $a+\omega bp^{1/3}+\omega^2cp^{2/3}\in \{a+bp^{1/3}+cp^{2/3},\omega(a+bp^{1/3}+cp^{2/3}),\omega^2(a+bp^{1/3}+cp^{2/3})\}$. The analyze of the three possibilities give a contradiction.

Comment: Beautiful proof. Thank you!